# Wordpress permission problems in Webbynode

Tags: wordpress, permissions, webbynode

I am trying to install (copy) Wordpress files in my Webbynode. I can copy the files. But when I try to upgrade automatically I get a lot of permission errors. I only can solve them using chmod 777 in folders and files, what is not secure.

I'd like to know if someone can explain in simple words who needs to be the owners of the files and folders and/or what is the best way to install wordpress in Webbynode in order to not get these errors.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over your server, which I understand you have with that provider, you can set the owners of the folders to the same user as the one with which Apache is running, so the permissions could be 755 and the rest of the world won't be able to write into them.

To find out which user Apache is running as you can use:

```
ps aux | grep apache
```

Sometimes the process is named "apache2", or also "httpd", instead of "apache".

Comment: Thanks. I used the command `chown -h -R www-data *` and now it is working to update, upgrade, install plugins, themes.